# react-hook-form defaultValues that is a date not rendering

Tags: reactjs, date, react-hook-form

I am quite new to react and javascript so please excuse me if this is a bit of a rudimentary question.

The simplified code is below or can be seen at https://codesandbox.io/s/react-form-date-issue-327fh?file=/src/App.tsx:48-63

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

type Person = {
  firstname :string;
  lastname :string;
  dob : Date;
  }

const App = (person: Person) => {

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<Person>( {defaultValues: person});
  
  const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data))
  })

  return (    
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input {...register("firstname", {required : 'Required'})} id = "firstname" type="text"/>
      <input {...register("lastname", {required : 'Required'})} id = "lastname" type="text"/>
      <input {...register("dob", {required : 'Required'})} id = "dob" type="date"/>      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App firstname = "Joe" lastname = "Blogs" dob = {new Date(2002,12,31)} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This gives me the following form which is prepopulated except for  the dd/mm/yyyy
[image]

The problem I have is

- I have a simple react hook form that uses a `type` which is used by `useForm`. In this case its called `Person`
- This form will be populated with `defaultvalues` that are retrieved from an API.
- The type that this form uses has a date in it.
- When the date is set as part of the `defaultvalues` in the `useForm` it is not rendered and all I get is dd/mm/yyyy
- When I submit the form the correct value is submitted

My question is how do I get the dob date box to display the underlying date rather than dd/mm/yyyy?

I can change the dob input to be of type text rather than date and the correct value is displayed but then there is of course no validation of the date or a date picker

Rather than passing in the type to `defaultValues` of useform I have also tried passing in a `defaultValue` to each of the inputs. This renders the date correctly (if i output the date to a string of correct format) but I would rather not have to set the defaultValue on each input as the type I am actually using is quite large and I thought it was quite nice just to bind the one object

`<input {...register("dob", {required : 'Required'})} id = "lastname" type="date" defaultValue = {person.dob.toISOString().substr(0, 10)}/>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That's because the `input type="date"` only accepts `string` type as a value, but here you're trying to set it to `Date` type. If you change it to a string, it works as expected: [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-form-date-issue-forked-3zutu?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: And I also forgot to mention that the date string has to be in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format in order for the `input type="date"` value to be displayed. You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: @Kapobajza. Thanks for you reply. I now understand that the input type of date has to be a string in the form YYYY-MM-DD. This I didnt know. I see how you have changed the type of dob to string and it now works. However, I have no control over the type being passed in. The Person type in the example is only one I created for this post.

Comment: @KiwinLondon you can just use the dob `date` type and convert it to a string with format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that when I use defaultvalues on useform rather than the defaultvalue on the input itself?

Comment: I wasn't implying putting the default value on the input itself, but rather at the place where you're getting the person data (maybe as a response from a server). Before returning the actual person data, add a new field or replace `dob` with a `YYYY-MM-DD` formatted string